# SQL query to totalize a value over time when an independent criteria is met

Tags: sql

I have an application where I need to sum (totalize) off spec product that is produced over a period where a criteria condition is met. The easiest way to explain this is with an example.

The data exists in one table **t_data** with columns:
- tagId (Nvarchar)
- timeStamp (Datetime)
- valueFloat (Float)

The tagId of the value to totalize is **myVal** and the criteria value is **myCrit**. I want to know the totalized value of **myVal** whenever **myCrit** is less than 10.

```
tagId    |  timeStamp  |  valueFloat  |  (comment)  
---------+-------------+--------------+--------------   
myCrit   |  08:01:00   |  12.0        |  myCrit starts good - no totalizing yet
myVal    |  08:01:00   |  10.0        |  
myCrit   |  08:02:00   |  9.0         |  myCrit goes bad take next myval as "start"
myVal    |  08:03:00   |  15.0        |  start
myCrit   |  08:04:00   |  8.5         |  
myVal    |  08:05:00   |  16.0        |  
myVal    |  08:06:00   |  20.0        |  end (20-15 totalized)
myCrit   |  08:07:00   |  10.5        |  myCrit is good take prev. myVal as "end"
myVal    |  08:08:00   |  25.0        |  
myCrit   |  08:09:00   |  9.0         |  myCrit bad take next myVal as "start"
myVal    |  08:10:00   |  30.0        |  start
myVal    |  08:11:00   |  40.0        |  end (40-30 totalized)
myCrit   |  08:12:00   |  11.0        |  myCrit good, take prev. myVal as "end"
```

The totalized value for the a query of the range of data shown should be (20-15 + 40-30) = 15.

So in summary I want to add the difference of myVal at the start and end of time segments. The start and end of the segments are marked by changes of myCrit to a good or bad value. How can I do this with a stored procedure?

Comment: So you compare 2 consecutive values of `myVal` and `myCrit`?

Comment: I see that you have used some undefined sorting in your table. It is not sorted by timeStamp. What column is used for sorting?

Comment: I compare consecutive values of `myCrit` then when it goes "off spec" (below 10.0) I take the next occuring `myVal` as the start value. When `myCrit` then goes "on spec" (above 10.0) I take the immediately previous `myVal` as the end value. The end value minus the start value for each "off spec" period is the totalized value of off spec product for that period. The sum of all totalized off spec values for a period should be returned by the query.

Comment: Sorry, there were some copy paste edits in the table. It should be sorted by timestamp for clarity of the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dang... Well, I think Cursors should always be a last result, but based on what I see in your sample data, they might make sense here.  This works:

```
DO language plpgsql $$
DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR SELECT tagId, valueFloat FROM t_data ORDER BY time_stamp;
DECLARE critval float = 10;
DECLARE last_bad boolean = false;
DECLARE gonecritical boolean = false;
DECLARE startval float = -9999;
DECLARE endval float = 0;
DECLARE totalized float = 0;
DECLARE ltagid varchar;
DECLARE lvalue float;
BEGIN
    OPEN mycursor;
    FETCH NEXT from mycursor INTO ltagid, lvalue;
    WHILE (FOUND) LOOP
      /* We have a record */

        /* Are we critical already or not? */
        if gonecritical then
            /* We are already in a critical chunk */
            IF ltagid = 'myVal' and startval = -9999 THEN
                startval = lvalue;
            END IF;
            if ltagid = 'myVal' then
                /* The "last" one we did will always be endval */
                endval = lvalue;
            END IF;
            if ltagid = 'myCrit' and lvalue >= critval then
                /* Yeah! This is the end of critical! */
                totalized = totalized + (endval - startval);
                goneCritical = false;
                startval = -9999;
            END IF;
        else
            /* We are NOT already in a critical chunk */
            if ltagid = 'myCrit' and lvalue < critval then
                /* Yikes we are going critical */
                gonecritical = true;
            END IF;
        end if;

        FETCH NEXT from mycursor INTO ltagid, lvalue;
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE mycursor;
     INSERT INTO t_result select totalized;
END;
 /* totalized has your value! */

$$
```

I did that in Postgres, but used a pretty generic SQL-based query syntax, so you should be able to use it easily in MSSQL or whatever you need.

Good luck!
Dave