# Totalize values of one group in one column conditionally from one table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table which is recording measured values into [Value] column with a [DateTime] column for time stamp and [TagName] column for showing which measurement it is. You can see below an example part of it.

```
DateTime                    TagName             Value
2019-02-16 17:04:19.5550000 CT027001_01.OUT_PV  520.254638671875
2019-02-16 17:04:19.5550000 FT027001_01.OUT_PV  29.6527767181396
2019-02-16 17:04:20.7270000 CT027001_01.OUT_PV  517.07177734375
2019-02-16 17:04:20.7270000 FT027001_01.OUT_PV  29.4444446563721
2019-02-16 17:04:22.0860000 CT027001_01.OUT_PV  516.203674316406
2019-02-16 17:04:22.0860000 FT027001_01.OUT_PV  29.2013893127441
2019-02-16 17:04:23.0910000 CT027001_01.OUT_PV  515.914367675781
2019-02-16 17:04:23.0910000 FT027001_01.OUT_PV  29.0451393127441
2019-02-16 17:04:23.4770000 CT027001_01.OUT_PV  515.914367675781
2019-02-16 17:04:23.4770000 FT027001_01.OUT_PV  29.0451393127441
2019-02-16 17:04:24.4820000 CT027001_01.OUT_PV  516.782409667969
2019-02-16 17:04:24.4820000 FT027001_01.OUT_PV  28.4461803436279
2019-02-16 17:04:25.0860000 CT027001_01.OUT_PV  516.782409667969
2019-02-16 17:04:25.0860000 FT027001_01.OUT_PV  28.4461803436279
```

Values are only recorded if value is changed. 
What I want to do is; I want to totalize the FT values when CT values are bigger than 600 and FT values are bigger than 10. I know how to totalize values with using LAG method, but I do not know how to filter conditions I mentioned.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT C.[DateTime], C.[TagName], C.[Value] FROM (
 SELECT [DateTime]
  ,[TagName]
  ,[Value]
 FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[History] 
 where TagName like '%CT027001%' and TagName= 'FT027001_01.OUT_PV' 
       AND [DateTime] > '2019-02-16' AND [DateTime] < '2019-02-17') C 
        WHERE C.[Value] > 10 AND C.[TagName] = 'FT027001_01.OUT_PV'
```

Expected Output:

```
TotalFlow 1500.0000
```

Comment: Please don't post code and data as an image. Both are text, please do post them as `text`. Images aren't helpful to the volunteers you're asking help from as they can't make use of it (we can't copy your SQL from an image and run it, nor the data). When you edit your post, please make sure you post your expected output as well (and your attempted(s)). Thanks.

Comment: Please indicate which version of SQL Server you're using.  How are the CT and FT values associated with each other?  And what @Larnu said about posting a question - [ask] and [mcve] have additional details.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784561/sql-query-to-totalize-a-value-over-time-when-an-independent-criteria-is-met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to relate two different records of the same table to each other, you must select from the same table twice by giving two different aliases and joining them together.

I also assume that you want to group by day. `CONVERT(date, FT.DateTime)` strips off the time part.

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, FT.DateTime) AS DateTime, FT.TagName, SUM(FT.Value) AS Total
FROM
    History FT
    INNER JOIN History CT
        ON FT.DateTime = CT.DateTime
WHERE
    FT.TagName LIKE 'FT%' AND
    CT.TagName LIKE 'CT%' AND
    CT.Value > 600 AND
    FT.Value > 10
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(date, FT.DateTime),
    FT.TagName
```

If the `DateTime` is not precise enough to pair the two records, you might also add this condition to the where clause (with `AND`)

```
SUBSTRING(FT.TagName, 3, 100) = SUBSTRING(CT.TagName, 3, 100)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Olivier Jacot-Descombes !